# Matlab: Adding two structs

Tags: matlab

I have:

```
A = 

a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
d: 4

B = 

e: 10
d: 10
b: 10
a: 10
```

I want to concatenate those two as the following.

```
new_struct = 

a: 11
b: 12
c: 3
d: 14
e: 10
```

The order of fields in 'new' does not matter.

I've been trying to learn efficient matlab programming. How would I do this without using for loops and if statements?

Comment: If you need to do this kind of operation, it would be wise to think *hard* if there is a more suitable data structure for your data than structs with different field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [CATSTRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842) and have a look at what Loren's got [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/15/concatenating-structs/).  I think you were hoping for a more elegant solution, but I think these techniques are what the community has settled.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is resolved by now, but for anyone else coming here from google, here's a function that will add two structs (although not quite in the manner described). It *does* use for loops and if statements, but hopefully it's useful to someone nonetheless.

```
function S = addStructs(S1, S2)
% S = addStructs(S1, S2)
%
% Given two structs S1 and S2, returns a struct S such that
% S.<fieldName> = S1.<fieldName> + S2.<fieldName> for all 
% fieldNames whose corresponding values are both numeric
% and the same length in both S1 and S2.
%
% If the values are not numeric or not the same length, the
% value from S1 is copied to S.
%
% This function will throw an error if the field names in
% S1 and S2 are not the same.
%
% Example:
%
% >> s1
% 
% s1 = 
% 
%       a: 1
%       b: 2
%       c: [1 2 3]
%     foo: 'bar'
% 
% >> s2
% 
% s2 = 
% 
%       a: 1
%       b: 4
%       c: 3
%     foo: 'baz'
% 
% >> addStructs(s1, s2)
% 
% ans = 
% 
%       a: 2
%       b: 6
%       c: [1 2 3]
%     foo: 'bar'

fNames1 = fieldnames(S1);
fNames2 = fieldnames(S2);

diff = setdiff(fNames1, fNames2);
if ~isempty(diff)
   error('addStructs: structures do not contain same field names')
end

numFields = length(fNames1);

for i=1:numFields

    % get values for each struct for this field
    fNameCell = fNames1(i);
    fName = fNameCell{:};
    val1 = S1.(fName);
    val2 = S2.(fName);

    % if field non-numeric, use value from first struct
    if (~isnumeric(val1) || ~isnumeric(val2) )
        S.(fName) = val1;

    % if fields numeric but not the same length, use value
    % from first struct
    elseif (length(val1) ~= length(val2) )
        S.(fName) = val1;

    % if fields numeric and same length, add them together
    else
        S.(fName) = val1 + val2;
    end
end

end
```